# Can my Service Activator have an overloaded function set as its Method in a SPEL expression

Tags: spring-integration

I have a gateway that looks like this

```
public interface MetadataIngestNotificationGateway {

     public boolean sendMetadataNotification(MetadataNotification notification);
     public boolean sendMetadataAssociationNotification(MetadataAssociationNotification notification);

}
```

I have a header enricher that looks like this

```
<int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="routingKey" expression="@routingKeyResolver.resolveRoutingKey(payload)" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

And I have a class that looks like this (its the routingKeyResolverBean)

```
public class RoutingKeyResolver {

    public String resolveRoutingKey(MetadataNotification obj) throws UnknownHostException {
        //...
        returns someStringBasedOnThisObject;
    }

    public String resolveReoutingKey(MetadataAssociationNotification obj) throws UnknownHostException {
        //...
        return someStringBasedOnThiObject;
    }
}
```

It all looks like it should work but I end up getting this error.
`Method call: Method resolveRoutingKey(MetadataAssociationNotification) cannot be found on RoutingKeyResolver type`

I claim that it CAN be found (I can see it), but the framework believes that it CANNOT. Could someone please help me find the error in my ways. I was not sure if this would actually work though it looks like it should.

I assume that I cannot have an expression that points at a function that is overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it is an issue of SpEL [compiler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-spel-compilation), which generate a class for that expression on the fly for the first call.

Meanwhile I'm trying to reproduce it, try this solution for your particular case:

```
<int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="routingKey" ref="routingKeyResolver" method="resolveReoutingKey"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```